# Collecting Tabular Input with improper indexes

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hope you all be doing fine.

**Flow**
Every time I hit the Add New button, an AJAX request is sent to server with the updated counter of indexes to controller. Now controller creates a new model at given index, develops a container row using a partial view and then converts it to Json and returns it back to show off the new record extending the current main container with the sub-container or row.

[image]
**Problem**
Everything works fine as long as we follow the normal flow of indexes. But when I make changes to the normal flow by adding/removing records (indexes) and then submit it (as shown in above image - indexes are not in normal flow, 2nd index is deleted), I get validation errors pointing the model values (the required ones) can not be left blank.

**Target**
I want to add model-instances to be added in my database if they are valid regardless of their index number. No matter what index they belong to, I want them to be submitted and treated like a model array that is in a sequence.

Here is the code I have in my main partial file:
**_partials/_edit_form**

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- container that has form and its operations in it -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">

<?php

    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'form_edit_resume_lang_multiple',
        'options' => [
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'class' => 'section_form',
        ],
    ]);

?>
    <div id="add_new_record_container">
    <!--
        Add new Item related item_container will be placed in here dynamically in parallel
        This loaded content is based on _add_new_form partial view
        Content is added via AJAX request caused by btn_add_new_record
    -->
    </div>

    <div class="row form_controls">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnCounter" id="hdnCounter" value="<?php echo count($languages); ?>" />
            <?php echo Html::a(T::t('main', 'Add New'), ['/oresume/resume-language/add-new-record', 'idresume'=>$model_resume->idresume], ['id'=>'btn_add_new_record', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary' ]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <?php echo Html::a(T::t('main', 'Cancel'), ['/oresume/attachment/discard-all-drafts'], ['class'=>'btn btn-default', 'id'=>'btnDiscardChanges', 'data'=>['confirm_message'=>T::t('main', 'Discard Changes?'), ] ]);?>
            <?php echo Html::submitButton(T::t('main', 'Save Changes'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($form->attributes);?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            <?php 
                $options = Json::htmlEncode($form->options);
                $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($form->attributes);          
            ?>

            $("#<?php echo $form->options['id'];?>").yiiActiveForm(<?php echo $attributes;?>, <?php echo $options;?>);

            $(".resume_languages").select2({
                tags: true,
                multiple: true,
                maximumSelectionLength: 1,
                language: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->language; ?>",
                allowClear: true,
                placeholder: {
                    idskill: "",
                    placeholder: "<?php echo T::t('main', 'Please select'); ?>"
                },
            });

            var attributes = <?php echo $attributes;?>; 
            for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
                $("#form_edit_resume_lang_multiple").yiiActiveForm('add', attributes[i]);
            }
        });
    </script>


<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- //container that has form and its operations in it -->
</div>
```

**Note:**
The hdnCounter inout field has the counter value. the initial counter is 0. When I hit "Add New" button, the AJAX request brings in a new model instance with proper look and feel as response and it is appended to main form container. After that counter gets incremented by 1.

Here is the code for my partial_view that is used as a base template to create a new 
**_partials/_add_new_form.php**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 item_container">

    <div class="row single_value_row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]idlanguage")->dropDownList($languages, ['style'=>['width'=>'100%'], 'class'=>'resume_languages', 'placeholder'=>T::t('main', 'Please select')]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]level")->dropDownList($proficiencyLevels, ['prompt' => T::t('main', 'Please Select')]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-left">
            <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn_remove_record" id="btnRemoveResumeLanguage-<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo T::t('main', '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'); ?></button>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]isDeleted")->hiddenInput(['class'=>'isDeleted_input'])->label(false); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]isFromDb")->hiddenInput(['class'=>'isFromDb_input'])->label(false); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#form_edit_resume_lang_multiple").yiiActiveForm('add', 'OresumeResumeLang[<?php echo $i; ?>]');

            $(".resume_languages").select2({
                tags: true,
                multiple: true,
                maximumSelectionLength: 1,
                language: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->language; ?>",
                allowClear: true,
                placeholder: {
                    idskill: "",
                    placeholder: "<?php echo T::t('main', 'Please select'); ?>"
                },
            });

            <?php $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($form->attributes);?>
            var attributes = <?php echo $attributes; ?>;
            for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
                $("#form_edit_resume_lang_multiple").yiiActiveForm('add', attributes[i]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Now Here is the code my my controller method that creates a new model on given index
**actionAddNewRecord**

```
public function actionAddNewRecord($idresume, $index)
{
    $model = new OresumeResumeLang();
    $model->idresume = $idresume;
    $model->isDeleted = 0;
    $model->isFromDb = 0;

    $response = [];

    $response['content'] = $this->renderPartial('_partials/_add_new_form', [
        'model' => $model, 'i'=>$index
    ]);

    return Json::encode($response);
}
```

Here is the code for Adding/Removing multiple instances - (managing tabular input)
**actionGetResumeLanguages**

```
    public function actionGetResumeLanguages($idresume)
    {
        $model_resume = OresumeResume::findOne($idresume);
        $models = OresumeResumeLang::getResumeLanguages($model_resume->idresume);

        $response = [];

        $postedArray = \Yii::$app->request->post('OresumeResumeLang');
        //         print_r($postedArray);

        if( count($postedArray) )  //case: Its a postback and we have some models in it
        {
            if(count($models) < count($postedArray) )//case: postback has more number of models as compared to in db
            {
                //  Generate empty models array to be filled by loadMultiple() method of model class
                //  create emoty models and add in models array counter so that
                //  we've equal number of sent / recieved models for processing
                for ($i=count($models); $i< count($postedArray); $i++ )
                {
                    $model = new OresumeResumeLang();
                    $model->idresume = $idresume;
                    $models[] = $model;
                }
            }
        }

        if( count($models) == 0) //  we need to check if this array has something to process
        {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['message'] = T::t('main', 'No records found to process');
        }

        //  if we have postback and if we have more models in it than
        //  in our database, and since we have created empty models
        //  to be filled-up now we can load posted models in our array
        if(OresumeResumeLang::loadMultiple($models, \Yii::$app->request->post())) //  load multiple models of models array
        {
            $status = true;

            foreach ($models as $model)
            {
                //  Delete models that are flaged to do so
                //  execute continue; statement after deletion

                //  Validate and save models that are to be saved/updated
                $model->idlanguage = OresumeResumeLang::getLanguageId($model->idlanguage);
                $model->level = ($model->level != null)? $model->level : OresumeResumeLang::LEVEL_BEGINNER;
                if( $model->validate() )    //  Case: Model data is valid
                {
                    //  Save Model in database
                    $status &= $model->save();
                }
                else
                {
                    $status = false;
//                     print_r($model->errors['idlanguage'][0]);
                    $response['message'] = T::t("main", "Storing of record \"{$model->idlanguage0->name}\" got some validation issues\n");
                }
            }

            if($status)
            {
                $model_resume = OresumeResume::findOne($model->idresume);
                $models = OresumeResumeLang::getResumeLanguages($model->idresume);

                $response['status'] = true;
                $response['content'] = $this->renderPartial('_partials/_edit_form', ['model_resume' => $model_resume, 'languages' => $models]);
                $response['counter'] = count($models);
                $response['message'] = T::t('main', 'Record(s) updated Successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                $response['status'] = false;
                //  $response['message'] = T::t('main', 'Records could not be updated.\n Something went wrong');
            }
        }
        else // case: page loads for the first time
        {
            $response['content'] = $this->renderPartial('_partials/_edit_form', ['model_resume'=>$model_resume, 'languages' => $models]);
        }

        return Json::encode($response);
    }
```

Edit:
I created index-2 and then deleted it. (caused the form to be created against index-2). Now Once again, I hit Add New (causing a new form to be created against index-3) I fill it with values and then submit the form to the server, I get the validation errors against form with index-2 pointing the values cannot be left blank. I am not able to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating new model based on new request to server each time you ask for a new record insertion. but when you delete it, you have not deleted that index in your model index. I guess this might be the reason.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I'll try this approach and see if it helps.

Comment: Can you please help and write some sample code for this? I am getting confused here.